# Invoke method on generic object without parameters with Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am working on a generic printer utility that prints whatever object might come along as long it presents an invokePrint() method. The context asks me for a PrintDialogEditor object I get through reflection in the following manner. I tried all sorts of paremeter for that invoke method along that troubleshooting offered through Oracle [IllegalArgumentException from Method.invoke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodTrouble.html) but I can't get passed that last line. My question: Does the Reflection API foresee operations on generic objects at all?

```
PrintDialogEditor pde = null;
U editor = au.getEditor(entity);
if(hasInvokePrint(editor)) {
  Method m = editor.getClass().getMethod("invokePrint");
  pde = (PrintDialogEditor) m.invoke(editor); // this line fails
```

I have been debugging along the Oracle troubleshooting for using the Method.invoke() method.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error stacktrace. Without knowing the actual problem it is kind of impossible to provide help.

Comment: The reflection API completely ignores generics. Generics are a compile time thing, reflection is a runtime thing. That's not the problem here. The info required the identify the problem isn't present in the question. Edit it, and add the stack trace. Also add the _actual_ definition of `class X{}` where X is whatever editor is an instance of (if you don't know - print `editor.getClass()` to standard out. We need the definition of _that_, as well as any relevant superclasses it has (if the `invokePrint` is defined there, show it). I'm guessing that the invokePrint method needs params.

Comment: Also, if you're using the module system (you have a `module-info.java` file and use the module stuff to run it), [A] don't, it's a bad system useful for OpenJDK itself and mostly nothing else, and [B] if the package isn't 'read' by the code that tries to invoke `invokePrint`, reflection just doesn't work.

Comment: Dear Rzwitserloot, after three hard days with a deficient Debuger, I finally found the issue: a ressource blocking  the invocation of that invokePrint method. Should I mention I am bound or better said constricted to a proprietary Eclipse clone offered by a third party vendor? Anyway Reflection is great.